# How to use a patch file in android

Tags: android, call, recorder

I have a HTC sensation(4.0.3) and trying for 2 way call recording.
So I decided to use "sensation_stock_2_6_35.patch" for installing rvoix call recorder.But I couldn't find a way to do that.

Please help me. Thanks!
(http://code.google.com/p/2-way-call-recording/source/browse/patches/sensation_stock_2_6_35.patch)

Answer (score 0):

May be late to answer,
but this link can be referred

http://drupal.org/node/707484

```
git apply -v [patch-name.patch]
```